# Confusion over animations in the Dope Sheet and NLA Editor

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet, nla-editor

I'm currently confused as to what's going on with my animations. If I click the star icon to lock a certain animation and mute the others, each animation works correctly. If I have none starred, the default animation is always my walking animation, and the animations don't play correctly if I select them from the Action list; parts of the mesh deform. The character's right foot for the walk animation looks as though he's hobbling or trying to walk on tip-toes.
I can have nothing selected in the NLA Editor or nothing from my Action list under the Dope Sheet, but it will always play my walking animation by default. I'm not sure why or how to change this.
It almost seems like one or two of my animations have inherited keyframes from other animations with the way they deform. I even tried deleting every key frame from every animation so nothing shows for each action, and yet I've noticed the hands still move slightly. o_O

Why animations are the 'right' ones according to Blender? The ones I can star under the NLA Editor or the ones that are broken via the Action list of the Dope Editor. I'll upload my save file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The action that will be played will be the priority one on the *NLA*, i.e. the one on top track, except:

- 1: If you've selected a strip in the *NLA* and pressed <kbd>tab</kbd> to edit its action in the *Dopesheet*/*Action Editor*. To come back to the normal *NLA* running, press <kbd>tab</kbd> again on the *NLA* (or press the X button on the right of the action name in the *Dopesheet*/*Action Editor*).
- 2: If you've loaded an animation in the *Dopesheet*/*Action Editor* mode from the dropdown menu. To come back to the normal *NLA* running, press the X button on the right of the action name.

But be careful: If the animation you've selected misses keyframes for some of its bones, these bones may be playing some inexplicable keyframes, actually coming from other NLA strips below your one or from previous animation. To prevent this to happen you can press the star icon of your track or mute the others. But the best thing to do is to keyframe your whole armature in *Pose* mode, at the beginning of each action, to make sure that no bone will inherit pose from another action, unless you have a good reason not to.

Also, about NLA strips: If you want the keyframes of an animation strip to continue to influence the armature even after the end of the strip length, choose the *Hold* option in the *Extrapolation* dropdown menu of the *Properties* panel of the *NLA* (activate with <kbd>N</kbd> > *Animations* > *Active Strip*.

About actions: Don't forget to press the F button on the right of the action name, in the *Dopesheet/Action Editor* mode. This way you're sure this action won't be deleted when you'll reopen your file, even if it's not used anywhere.

About your foot hobbling, it happens in the middle of your action, frame 20 when the left foot is forward. To fix it, go in *Pose* mode, select all the bones at frame 0 (or at least the leg bones), <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, come to frame 20, where the pose is supposed to be inverted, select all your bones and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>i</kbd> to keyframe the pose. It works.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the suggestion. :) How do you change the priority animation, such as from Walk to Idle? Is that even possible?
I've also noticed that if I play the walk animation and then select the Idle animation either from the Action list or pressing tab on the strip, the idle becomes deformed and looks like some weird mech from a Metal Gear Solid game lol.

Comment: I'm still really confused when setting up a new Action or strip. I'll click on the cross to remove the current one, create a new one and name it, go to the NLA Editor, add a keyframe for a bone or two, and click on the drop-down arrow to add the strip, but it still incorporates the walking animation to the new one, making it look deformed. :-\

Comment: to play a strip then another one you can put the second strip after the first one on the same track, or let the second one on his own track below, but in this case make sure that the first strip extrapolation is set to Nothing (in the N panel, on the right of the NLA editor > Animations tab > Active Strip > Extrapolation), otherwise the others strips below won't play.

Comment: Also, if you bring some modifications to your action, make sure that you've refreshed the strip length, in the N panel > Animations > Action Clip > Sync Length + click on Now button

Comment: oh and another thing you need to know: if there is no keyframe for some bones on your top strip, the keyframes for these bones of the strip below will be taken into account

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just getting more and more confused. What exactly does Extrapolation do? What's its purpose?

I'm still getting the issue where every new Action/Strip I set up is playing my walk animation and adding keyframes to the new strip is just making the walk animation go all deformed. :(

Comment: you should work on some NLA tutorials because it's getting hard to explain. Extrapolation is the way the strip continues or not to influence. If it is set on Hold, the strips below this strip won't be able to play, if it is set on Nothing the strips below will be able to play. But note that if the action above another has not keyframed some bones, then the armature will be able to play the keyframes of the action below. That's a good reason to always set a keyframe for the whole armature at the end of an action, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Okay, so if I don't keyframe all of the bones in a strip, this is why some of them are inherited in another strip and causing the animations to deform?

Comment: that's what I told you in my answer: ", it’s probably because at the beginning of this new action you haven’t determined any new keyframe for this bone, so it will keep the one determined by the previous action."

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to process and get my head around it all.

Comment: sure it takes time to understand  ;)

Comment: I've added a recent save to the first post. I'm not sure if you can figure it out, but the right arm has inherited something as it keeps twisting round a bit in the last keyframe causing a noticeable judder when it reloops. I can't work out what's causing it.

Comment: Apologies if you have covered this, but, what is the correct way of activating and deactivating each animation? I thought that selecting the desired animation from the Action list would be it, but it doesn't make any difference; it keeps playing the default animation, which is my walk cycle. Selecting a strip so it turns orange doesn't work either. Is it only via pressing Tab or clicking on a star?

Comment: I'm looking at your file and trying to find where your problem comes from. About your question, what do you mean by activating and deactivating? If you mean you want to work on one of your animation to make some modification, you can either select it in the NLA and press tab, or select it in the Dopesheet/Action mode.

Comment: It just seems like whenever I go to create a whole new animation, I'll create a new one from the Dope Sheet, but scrubbing along the timeline, an animation plays, which makes me wonder if this is why it's inheriting keyframes from other animations. I'll select all the bones, add a keyframe, a strip is made in the NLA Editor, but I notice something has been inherited. Like with that right arm's rotation I mentioned you're looking into. And that same arm keeps twitching in a new strip.

Comment: the arm problem comes from another strip below this one, there are keyframes lacking for somewhere on your arm in your walk cycle, and as I explained, if you don't set keyframe for a bone it will play a keyframe set in one of the animations below, there must be a setup to prevent that but that what's happening here. Also to make it easier to switch from NLA to Dopesheet animation, you should begin your timeline at frame 0.

Comment: Also make sure that the first pose and last pose of your animation (0 and 40) are the same. And the pose at frame 1 is not good, it will make the armature jerky, you should delete it and rework it

Comment: If you want to create a brand new animation, go in the Dopesheet/Action Editor mode, click New, and if you want your armature to be reset at its rest position, select all the bones and press alt G and alt R then i to keyframe, you're now sure that all your bones are at their basic position, then begin to work.

Comment: I'm editing my main answer to try to introduce all these points, I hope it will help.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to bear that in mind when I do a new animation. :) Now I've gone and deleted every keyframe from every animation, and the bones for the arms still keep twitching as though they've inherited a keyframe. I've no idea what's going on with this...

Comment: again, keyframes from other tracks, you should click on the star icon to only play your track, but more generally, always keyframe your whole armature at the beginning of an action to make sure it will be the only one playing, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: I think it's related to the two Jump strips. All the keyframes have been deleted, but there's another green strip at the top of each one with what looks like three keyframes. No idea how to delete these though.

Comment: Am I best clicking on the small speaker/channel next to each strip? It says the channel will contribute to the result. If this is muted will that prevent keyframes from being inherited?

Comment: when you work on your strips and animations you could use the speaker or star, but you should also try to make good animations, i.e. animations with keyframes for all the bones at the very beginning, so that it prevents any influence from any other tracks

Comment: But just to clarify, that speaker prevents keyframes from being inherited, right...?
Thanks for all your help though. I *think* I've got my animations sorted and working correctly. Plus, I've learnt a bit more about the Dope Sheet/NLA Editor. :)

Just one final quick question: what does NLA stand for?

Comment: It depends when you mute the other tracks, if you do it after it read the keyframe of a bone, the bone will stay at this position, that's why it's always better to keyframe your whole armature in Pose mode at the beginning of an action, you're sure you won't have any bad surprise. NLA = non-linear animation. It is made to mix, combine, repeat animations.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll be sure to keyframe the whole armature as you say, but I'll also click on the small speaker as well. :)